# Does the web3.eth.contract.new error object has a transactionHash?

Tags: web3js, contract-deployment

Does the web3.eth.contract.new error object has a transactionHash?

https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethcontract

I couldn't find anything about how the error object is structured.

Cheers,
Mario